# Using python to remove file metadata?

Tags: python, excel, metadata, shutil

I'm periodically asked to remove the metadata of a file before it goes to the client. I was recently asked to do it for a very large number of pdf and excel files -- so many that writing a script seemed like a natural solution.

A quick google led me to [shutil.copyfile(src, dst)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html):

> Copy the contents (no metadata) of the file named src to a file named dst. dst must be the complete target file name; look at shutil.copy() for a copy that accepts a target directory path. If src and dst are the same files, Error is raised. The destination location must be writable; otherwise, an IOError exception will be raised. If dst already exists, it will be replaced. Special files such as character or block devices and pipes cannot be copied with this function. src and dst are path names given as strings.

However, if I do something like:

```
shutil.copyfile('excel metadata tester_v1.xlsx', 'excel metadata tester_v1_stripped.xlsx')
```

Where 'excel metadata tester_v1.xlsx' is a file whose metadata I want gone, the file's metadata (author, date created, date modified, etc.) persists in 'excel metadata tester_v1_stripped.xlsx'.

I know I must be missing something obvious. Anyone know what it is?

Comment: There are different kinds of metadata.  What you're calling metadata is actually part of the data as far as the file itself is concerned (i.e., it is contained inside the file).  There's no generic way to remove it; you'll need to use libraries that handle each format (i.e., a PDF library to manipulate PDF metadata, an XLS library to manipulate XLS metadata).  What `shutil` is talking about is file-level metadata like the creation/modification time.

Comment: The `metadata` referred to in `shutil` is filesystem metadata, like the owner of the file, write permissions, etc. The metadata inside an Excel file is totally different.

Comment: For Excel, at least, I would think that using Win32com via [pywin32](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pywin32) to automate Excel itself would be your best bet, although documentation on the API to Excel is not easy to find.

Answer (score 4):

```
import win32com.client as win32com    
book = r'file_path'
excel = win32com.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(book, Local=True)
wb.RemovePersonalInformation = True
wb.Close(SaveChanges=1)
excel.Quit()
```