# Delete all metadata from excel using python

Tags: python, excel, win32com

Is there a way to delete all metadata of excel files using python?

It would be preferable to use built-in python libraries such as os or win32com.client

Comment: Same question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31934658/using-python-to-remove-file-metadata

Comment: There was no answer to the question. I suggested my solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just solved the issue by using **win32com.client**

```
import win32com.client as win32com    
book = r'file_path'
excel = win32com.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(book, Local=True)
wb.RemovePersonalInformation = True
wb.Close(SaveChanges=1)
excel.Quit()
```